# No active image found in material

Tags: export

I think I'm following all steps to correctly bake multiple objects.
I'm trying to bake multiple objects (using procedural materials) into a single image.

I already got to do this with materials using image textures, but now I just want to use single colors for the objects.
Following all steps, when baking, I get: `No active image found in material "Bege" (0) for object "Base"` . However, all slots for the baked image are active. What's wrong?

[image]

Here a video with the steps: https://youtu.be/Ew1eclUXl6M

Comment: Hi :) What steps are you following? Please [edit that information](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/199676/edit) into your Q. Thanks :)

Comment: Sounds like you forgot to leave your "bake result" image selected in the node graph before you hit the bake button.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett All nodes for the baked result are selected. If you download the project, you can see. However, I keep getting this error.

Comment: I sent a video with the steps in the OP.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, still as of the current state of the Q, it relies on external links for the necessary information to provide an answer.It is much better to  provide all information as text in the body of your question, so that users who would like to answer, and *more importantly, future users* do not need to rely on external resources that may move or go offline later. Thanks :)

Comment: @Timaroberts I was forced to generate an external link because here I cannot embed videos directly in the post.

Answer (score 1):

The problem of the "No active image found in material" error message was simply because the "Use Nodes" was unchecked in this material.
[image]

Checking it, solved the problem.